# How to reset the state of any class from Navigation drawer flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am writing an application which has the navigation drawer  Whenever I try to open an activity from the navigation drawer my class loads first time successfully and give me the desired output as I've written code for selecting image from gallery in `initState` method, it allow me to select image from gallery first time. But when I click on the same tab again from Navigation drawer it doesn't reset the state of this class , I need to access Image picking code each time when I click again on same tab in Navigation drawer. Here is my code.

**NavigationDrawer class**

```
  _getDrawerItemWidget(int pos, String title) {



switch (pos) {
  case 0:
    if(title.contains("From Gallery"))

          return new TextRobo();
    else
      return new TranslateLangue();

    break;
  case 1:
    return new BarCodeRobo();
  case 2:
    return new TranslateLangue();

  default:
    return new Text("Error");
}
}




return new Scaffold(
appBar: new AppBar(
  iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
  title: new Text("App title",
    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
),

  drawer: new Drawer(
    child: new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container( height: 140.0, color: Colors.orange,
        child: new Center(child:
          new Text('App title', style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
          fontSize:25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        ),
        new Column(
            children: drawerOptions)
      ],
    ),

  ),
  body: _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedDrawerIndex, fragment_class  ),
);
}
}
```

**TextRobo class**

```
class TextRobo extends StatefulWidget {

TextRobo1()
{

  createState();
}
  @override
 _TextRoboState createState() => new _TextRoboState();
}

class _TextRoboState extends State<TextRobo> {



 File _imageFile;



 @override
 void initState() {
 // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  _getAndScanImage();

  }

  Future<void> _getAndScanImage() async {
   setState(() {
    _imageFile = null;

  });

  final File imageFile =
  await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);


 setState(() {
   _imageFile = imageFile;
  });
}

}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code for your initState(() {}) ?

Comment: please see TextRobo class, I've written my code in TextRobo's `initState` method

Comment: override dispose() function in TextRobo class and set _imageFile = null . 
please let me know if this helps.

Comment: no this is not working.

Comment: I need to call `initState` method somehow, when I re click on same tab from NavigationDrawer. actually I need to create state of my class again.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different approaches you could take to doing this. But first - have you followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@kashifmin/flutter-setting-up-a-navigation-drawer-with-multiple-fragments-widgets-1914fda3c8a8)? It is.... less than great.

The major issue is that it isn't using flutter's build-in navigation mechanism but rather changing an existing page. That means that you don't get to take advantage of a number of things that flutter does for you.

As to why initState is only being called once, it is most likely because flutter intelligently caches widget for you. Since your widget is ostensibly the 'same' even if you create a new instance, it won't bother remaking the state but rather will use the existing one in the name of performance.

What I'd advise is a bit of a re-write & refactor.

Something like this should do if your app is relatively simple (i.e. a set of pages you can switch between using a drawer:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
    return new MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: pageName(Pages.red),
      routes: {
        pageName(Pages.red): (context) => PageBase(title: pageName(Pages.red), page: ColouredPage(color: Colors.red)),
        pageName(Pages.green): (context) =>
            PageBase(title: pageName(Pages.green), page: ColouredPage(color: Colors.green)),
        pageName(Pages.blue): (context) =>
            PageBase(title: pageName(Pages.blue), page: ColouredPage(color: Colors.blue)),
      },
      // not actually used, needed in case flutter started with intent specifying unsupported route
      home: Container(),
    );
  }
}

enum Pages { red, green, blue }

String pageName(Pages page) {
  switch (page) {
    case Pages.red:
      return "Red";
    case Pages.green:
      return "Green";
    case Pages.blue:
      return "Blue";
  }
}

class PageBase extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Widget page;

  const PageBase({Key key, @required this.page, @required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: page,
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text(pageName(Pages.red)),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(pageName(Pages.red));
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(pageName(Pages.blue)),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(pageName(Pages.blue));
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(pageName(Pages.green)),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(pageName(Pages.green));
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColouredPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color;

  const ColouredPage({Key key, this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ColouredPageState createState() => _ColouredPageState();
}

class _ColouredPageState extends State<ColouredPage> {
  Color color;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    color = Colors.white;
    new Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        color = widget.color;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
    );
  }
}
```

If you push a page on top of one of the existing pages and then eventually return, you can use `Navigator.push()` with a handler for when it returns, then retrigger your function then.